# Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable and that $\int_a^b f (x)dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_0 \in [a, b]$, and define $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ via
$$
\begin{cases}
    0 & x \ne x_0\\
    k & x= x_0
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $f$ is  Riemann integrable and that $\int_a^b f (x)dx = 0$.

I know that I need to show that the lower and upper Riemann sums must be equal, but in my mind they are not equal, because at the point $x=x_0$, it will have an upper sum of $k$ but a lower sum of $0$. However, I understand and can visualize how the entire integral is equal to $0$.

Edit: I find the upper Riemann sum by
$$
U(f,P_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n M_i\Delta x_i.
$$
I know that $\Delta x_i =\frac{1}{n}$, but I don't know how to write $M_i$ because the function will suddenly jump up to $k$ at a certain point.

Comment: You are missing the $\Delta x$ term

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable if it is continuous almost everywhere.   Almost everywhere would be all but a set of points of measure 0.  But, if you haven't learned measure theory, let's say except for countably many points.  At those points where it fails to be continuous, you can fix the discontinuity if you replace that point with the limit of the function approaching that point.

Comment: @DougM That's dangerously circular. How would you prove that a function is Riemann integralble iff it is continuous almost everywhere if you're stuck at this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what I consider the salient points in the other answers, so here we go.

1. What I always called *the convenient criterion for integrability* in my teaching is this: $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a partition $P$ with $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$.
2. Create a partition as follows. I will suppose $a<x_0<b$. You can take care of the other cases. If $k=0$, the function is the zero function and there's nothing to do (I hope).

Given $\epsilon>0$, let $P$ be the partition $t_0=a$, $t_1=x_0-\delta$, $t_2=x_0+\delta$, $t_3=b$. We choose $\delta>0$ small enough so that $t_0<t_1<t_2<t_3$ and then small enough so that $2|k|\delta<\epsilon$. If $k>0$, we have $U(f,P) = 2k\delta$ and $L(f,P)=0$. If $k<0$, we have $U(f,P) = 0$ and $L(f,P) = 2k\delta$. In either event, we have $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. [You should draw pictures to see what's going on here. I'm leaving it to you to write out explicitly the formulas for $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$.]

Combining 1 and 2, we have shown $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. A very important point is that we do *not* always need to use a partition into subintervals of equal length.

Comment: The "convenient criterion" is better known as *Riemann's criterion* since he gave it first.  A student who has not encountered it cannot be said to have studied the Riemann integral at all really.

Comment: I am familiar with Riemann’s role here. I wasn’t claiming to have created the criterion, merely to have named it something my students actually remembered for years.

Comment: Of course.  For students I would offer three  historical criteria: Riemann's criterion, Hankel's criterion  and Lebesgue's criterion.   For elementary students they can only be "informed" that the latter concerns points of discontinuity.  Hankel's criterion concerns the oscillation of a function and is suitable for elementary analysis students who are not quite ready for measure zero sets.

Comment: Why would this approach not be enough when $x_0=a$ or $x_0=b$?

Comment: You just have to modify the partition in an obvious way. The main idea is the same.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. However, if $k<0$, don't we have $U(f,P)=0$ and $L(f,P)=-2k\delta$?

Comment: Nope. The lower sum is negative!

Comment: Yes, so shouldn't we write $-2k\delta$ instead of $2k\delta$?

Comment: No, $k$ is negative, remember!

Answer (score 3):

You make upper and lower sums by partitioning the interval $[a,b]$ into subintervals. The final upper and lower sums are the limits you approach as these subintervals get narrower and narrower.

Assuming $k\geq0$, the upper sum is $k$ when the subintervals are $1$ wide (for $k\leq0$ it is the lower sum that equals $k$ while the upper sum is $0$). What happens to the upper sum when the subintervals are narrower than $1$?

Comment: I think I understand this conceptually, but I'm having a tough time writing my ideas algebraically.

Comment: Then I would start by making a few drawings, with more and more narrow subintervals. See what the total area of the corresponding rectangles turns out to be in each case.

Answer (score 2):

The upper and lower sums will not be equal, but the upper and lower integrals will be. I'm not sure what notation you use, so I will use the one I am most familiar with. For a partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, the upper and lower sums are respectively \begin{align*}
U(f,P) &= \sum^n_{i=1} \left(\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)\right)(x_i-x_{i-1}), \\
L(f,P) &= \sum^n_{i=1} \left(\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)\right)(x_i-x_{i-1}).
\end{align*} Note that the width of the intervals come into play here. You are right that the supremum or infimum of $f$ will take the value $k$ for one (or maybe two) of those intervals, but the width of those intervals could be very small so that contribution can be made as small as you like.